# Linking from an activity to a fragment activity with a button using actionBarSherlock

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock, adt, android-fragmentactivity

I made a project wherein when you click a button from the MainActivity, it will lead to a fragment activity. But I can't seem to make it work.

Here's a snippet of my code for the button in MainActivity:

```
Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener () {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), page3.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    }) ;
```

Here's my snippet for page3 where the button from MainActivity leads to:

```
package com.example.pixelapp3;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

public class page3 extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);
    setContentView(mViewPager);

    final ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Fragment 1"), page3a.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Fragment 2"), page3b.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Fragment 3"), page3c.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Fragment 4"), page3d.class, null);
}
```

}

Here's the page3.xml snippet:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".mainActivity" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/pager"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's page3a.java:

```
package com.example.pixelapp3;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;


public class page3a extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.page3a, null);
}

}
```

Here's the logCat when I click the button that doesn't work:

```
  06-04 10:46:14.871: I/ActionBarSherlock(907): Registering ActionBarSherlockCompat with qualifier @com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock$Implementation(api=7, dpi=-1)
06-04 10:46:14.871: I/ActionBarSherlock(907): Registering ActionBarSherlockNative with qualifier @com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock$Implementation(api=14, dpi=-1)
06-04 10:46:14.971: I/ActionBarSherlock(907): Using implementation: ActionBarSherlockNative
06-04 10:46:14.971: D/ActionBarSherlock(907): [<ctor>] activity: com.example.pixelapp3.page3@41219338, flags: 1
06-04 10:46:14.971: D/ActionBarSherlock(907): [setContentView] view: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager@4121c920
06-04 10:46:14.971: D/ActionBarSherlock(907): [setContentView] view: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager@4121c920, params: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams@4122b4f0
06-04 10:46:15.212: D/ActionBarSherlock(907): [getActionBar]
06-04 10:46:15.222: D/ActionBarSherlock(907): [getActionBar]
06-04 10:46:15.361: V/21st Polling:(907): clicked
06-04 10:46:15.671: D/dalvikvm(907): GC_CONCURRENT freed 178K, 4% free 8234K/8519K, paused 74ms+88ms, total 260ms
06-04 10:46:15.671: D/AndroidRuntime(907): Shutting down VM
06-04 10:46:15.681: W/dalvikvm(907): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.pixelapp3.page3a cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:394)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.example.pixelapp3.TabsAdapter.getItem(TabsAdapter.java:97)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:97)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:829)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:979)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:911)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1432)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1850)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1102)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1275)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-04 10:46:15.761: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

[Here's the MainActivity](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lgvpp04avoum7s9/step1.png)

[Here's the page3(including page3a to page3d fragments](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dcsre65l0gqt8ds/step2.png)

I've been stuck here for days. Any type of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't really interpret logCat errors that much. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this button implementation instead :

```
 in your layout : 
       <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="yourmethod"
        android:text="button2" />

your code :

     public void yourmethod(View v){
   //do somthing on button press 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!

we have basically the same button layout, the only difference is that my text="@string/button2" when I use your syntax, the button shows errors that somehow runs the program on some Android platforms and crashes on others.

Really appreciate it!

Comment: What is the usual code to use to open a new activity? It's using intents right? Here's what I have used in by clickButton action:

public void onClick(View v) {
         
          Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), page5.class);
          startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
         }

Comment: yes its using intent but when your using fragment you will use it this way :
Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(),page5.class);
startActivity(intent);
use getActivity().getBaseContext() instead of v.getContext() and double check that your activity is defined in your minifest

Comment: I tried doing so with this code: 
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(),page3.class);


but is having an error:
method getActivity() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

and yes, the activity is defined in my manifest. Is this how you have it in mind?

<activity
            android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
      android:name=".page4"
      android:label="@string/button3">
  </activity>

Comment: correction it the manifest code should be this:
<activity
            android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
      android:name=".page3"
      android:label="@string/button2">
  </activity>

Comment: yes its right , i think i missed something my solution was if you have the button in the fragment but if you have the button in the main activity the correct way to start an activity using intent would be:
Intent Intent = new Intent( MainActivity.this,page3.class );
startActivity(Intent);

Comment: Thanks, I made the code like so:

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,page3.class);
          startActivity(intent);

No errors or warnings, but when I run the app on the emulator and click the button, the fragment would still not load.

Am I missing something on my page3.java file?

Comment: The code you gave works on other pages, the problem is with opening the fragment page/s.

Comment: can you try to run it in a device instead of the Emulater ?
are you using the button implementation i gave you or the old one using  button2.setOnClickListene .. ?

Comment: I ran the app on the emulator, on a Samsung S Duos, as well as an S3 Mini. Both of their OS are compatible with the app.

Comment: in page3 class you can use normal setContentView(R.layout.page3); 
exactly like a normal activity

Comment: Tried it. Works, BUT, it doesn't show the other fragment pages.

Comment: you mean that you want to show a fragment each time you click in a tab ?

Comment: if i answered the main question and it works can you mark my answer as accepted :) and as for the inflating fragments in tab click you need to implement 
ActionBar.TabListener as you can see in this answer :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721949/implementing-a-tablistener-using-the-support-library

Comment: I've edited and included images in the original question, that's what I was trying to ask about in general.

Comment: I already have my tabs and fragments readied, the only problem is when the button is clicked, it does not load the fragment.

Comment: all the layouts and functions are working quite ok already, and the only remaining problem is to allow proper linking from the activity through the button to the fragments. Once done, I can fix the ui, design and layout then there's my first android app :)

Btw, I really really appreciate your help. Thank you once again. :)

Comment: try to edit the question and add the code for page3a.class that supposed to be one of the fragments ..

Comment: Hi, I have included the page3a.java codes in the original question right before the logCat.

Comment: If you like, I could send you my project files so that it would be much easier to explain

Answer (score 0):

The interesting (to you) part is what follows `FATAL EXCEPTION`

You appear to be setting up a ViewPager and at some point in this process you are trying to cast an object of type `com.example.pixelapp3.page3a` to a Fragment class. As the object is not a fragment, it is throwing an exception.

That is as much as I can tell from the code you provided.

I would try to get the simple stuff working before attempting to complicate matters with tabs and ViewPager's

Comment: Thanks! Here's my code for page3a:

<blockquote>
package com.example.pixelapp3;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;


public class page3a extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.page3a, null);
 }

}
</blockquote>

Could you help me with what went wrong?

Comment: Your code is too complex to diagnose from tiny snippets but nowhere do I see you actually create a fragment and pass it into your actionbar. Have a look at the many examples on the internet such as http://arvid-g.de/12/android-4-actionbar-with-tabs-example