# How do you start a fragment when a button is clicked?

Tags: android, button, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I have tried several methods but I can't seem to make them work.

[Here's my main activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6vEz.png)

and when the button is clicked, it should open the start of the fragment,

[like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGukF.png)

A little help will be very much appreciated.

By the way, I'm using the actionSherlock plugin for the fragments

Comment: What's your code? There are many ways to achieve this.

Comment: could I send you my project files?

Comment: here's a link to my previous post which contains most of the code snippets:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909193/linking-from-an-activity-to-a-fragment-activity-with-a-button-using-actionbarshe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your Activity with 2 tabs,

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public Fragment frag1;
    public Fragment frag2;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.Tab tab1 = bar.newTab();
        ActionBar.Tab tab2 = bar.newTab();

        tab1.setText("");
        tab1.setIcon(R.drawable.abs__ic_menu_share_holo_dark);
        tab2.setText("");
        tab2.setIcon(R.drawable.abs__ic_voice_search);




            tab1.setTabListener(new MyTabListener());
            tab2.setTabListener(new MyTabListener());

            bar.addTab(tab1);
            bar.addTab(tab2);



    }

    private class MyTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

            switch (tab.getPosition()) {
            case 0:

                if (frag1 == null) {
                    // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
                    frag1 = Fragment.instantiate(getApplicationContext(),
                            FeedsActivity.class.getName());
                    ft.add(android.R.id.content, frag1, "Feeds");
                } else {
                    // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
                    ft.show(frag1);
                }
                return;

            case 1:
                if (frag2 == null) {
                    // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
                    frag2 = Fragment.instantiate(getApplicationContext(),
                            ProfileActivity.class.getName());
                    ft.add(android.R.id.content, frag2, "Profile");
                } else {
                    // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
                    ft.show(frag2);
                }
                return;


        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (frag1 != null) {
                // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
                switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                case 0:
                    ft.hide(frag1);
                    return;
                case 1:
                    ft.hide(frag2);
                    return;

                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }
}
```

Start this activity when button clicks

fragm1.java

```
    public class fragm1 extends Fragment {


@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflating layout
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment, container, false);
        // We obtain layout references

        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        // Button reset=(Button)findViewById(R.id.reset);




    }





}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try, I'll let you know.

Comment: I'm encountering some errors, i think it has to do with my imports. Here are my imports:

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

could you check on what imports I've been missing?

Comment: You are using the native actionbar librarys. Import the relevant sherlock librays.

Comment: it's already included:

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

Comment: Have you import your sherlok libaray to you project? (By right clicking the project and selecting properties) ?

Comment: I fixed the errors, but when the button is clicked, the fragments still don't start. Here's a link to my current file:  
goo(dot)gl/q1jPk

Comment: when I redirected the button link to either child fragments (frag1 or frag2) the pages load. But when I link the button to parent fragment(page6) the app crashes

Comment: Start your fragment using this code,  Button foo=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
  foo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent search = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this,
      Page6.class);
    
    startActivityForResult(search, 0);
    
   }
  });

Comment: Your code works perfectly for other pages, BUT when I use it to redirect to the parentFragment, the app still crashes. I think the problem is how I start the parent fragment. Or the child fragments

Comment: Here are the codes for my parentFragment(page6) and child fragments(frag1 and frag2): http://goo(dot)gl/dvMDT

Could you check what I did wrong?

Comment: I also tried linking the code button you gave me directly to frag1 or frag2, and they open without any errors in the logCat. So, I'm not really sure but there probably is something wrong with my page6(mainFragment) code

Comment: you need to extend your frag1 and frag2 to Fragment, not SherlockFragmentActivity. See my edited answer

Comment: Hi, thanks. But it still doesn't start the fragment properly, have you seen the codes?

Comment: edited the code to be this:

View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1, container, false);

Comment: From where you want to start the parent fragmentactivity? from another activity?

Comment: have you declared your parent fragment activity in your manifest? please post your error log.

Comment: Also try adding setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); in your parent fragment

Comment: I tried: a) setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); and setContentView(R.layout.page6); in my page6(parentFragment) but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Look at your logcat output in eclipse, and double click the line 06-10 16:38:29.398: E/AndroidRuntime(1489): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.pixelapp3.frag1 cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
So that your line caused error will be get highlighted in eclipse editor
paste that line here..