# ActionBar.TabListener with support library

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I am trying to write tabListener using support library. However, I am not sure if I am on the right track. Could you please examine my code and give me feedback?

SimpleTabListener.java

```
public class SimpleTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
Context _context;
String _tabFragmentClassName;
Fragment _tabFragment = null;
FragmentTransaction _ft;

public SimpleTabListener(Context context, String tabFragmentClassName)
{
    _context = context;
    _tabFragmentClassName = tabFragmentClassName;

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    if(_tabFragment==null)
    {
        _tabFragment = Fragment.instantiate(_context, _tabFragmentClassName);
        ActionBarActivity mActivity = (ActionBarActivity) _context; 
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        _ft=ft;
        _ft.add(android.R.id.content, _tabFragment);
        _ft.commit();
    }

    else
        _ft.attach(_tabFragment);

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    _ft.detach(_tabFragment);       
}

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener1 = new SimpleTabListener(this, "com.example.actionbartabbednav_p5.fragment1");
    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab();
    tab1.setText("Blablaaaa");
    tab1.setTabListener(tabListener1);
    actionBar.addTab(tab1);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Logcat

07-10 15:04:45.210: E/AndroidRuntime(5695): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

07-10 15:04:45.210: E/AndroidRuntime(5695): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.actionbartabbednav_p5/com.example.actionbartabbednav_p5.MainActivity}: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.actionbartabbednav_p5.fragment1: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public

07-10 15:04:45.210: E/AndroidRuntime(5695):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)

07-10 15:04:45.210: E/AndroidRuntime(5695):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)

07-10 15:04:45.210: E/AndroidRuntime(5695):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)

07-10 15:04:45.210: E/AndroidRuntime(5695):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)

07-10 15:04:45.210: E/AndroidRuntime(5695):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

07-10 15:04:45.210: E/AndroidRuntime(5695):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

07-10 15:04:45.210: E/AndroidRuntime(5695):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)

07-10 15:04:45.210: E/AndroidRuntime(5695):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

07-10 15:04:45.210: E/AndroidRuntime(5695):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

07-10 15:04:45.210: E/AndroidRuntime(5695):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)

07-10 15:04:45.210: E/AndroidRuntime(5695):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)

07-10 15:04:45.210: E/AndroidRuntime(5695):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

07-10 15:04:45.210: E/AndroidRuntime(5695): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.actionbartabbednav_p5.fragment1: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public

07-10 15:04:45.210: E/AndroidRuntime(5695):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:411)

07-10 15:04:45.210: E/AndroidRuntime(5695):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:379)

07-10 15:04:45.210: E/AndroidRuntime(5695):     at com.example.actionbartabbednav_p5.SimpleTabListener.onTabSelected(SimpleTabListener.java:33)

07-10 15:04:45.210: E/AndroidRuntime(5695):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplICS$TabWrapper.onTabSelected(ActionBarImplICS.java:558)

07-10 15:04:45.210: E/AndroidRuntime(5695):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:587)

07-10 15:04:45.210: E/AndroidRuntime(5695):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.addTab(ActionBarImpl.java:516)

07-10 15:04:45.210: E/AndroidRuntime(5695):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.addTab(ActionBarImpl.java:502)

07-10 15:04:45.210: E/AndroidRuntime(5695):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplICS.addTab(ActionBarImplICS.java:247)

07-10 15:04:45.210: E/AndroidRuntime(5695):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplJB.addTab(ActionBarImplJB.java:20)

Fragment1.java

```
package com.example.actionbartabbednav_p5;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

    Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    return view;
}
}
```

Comment: Please mention the issue you are having little more specifically.

Comment: I added logcat, could you check it out, now?

Comment: The exception is clear: do you have a class called `fragment1` which is a fragment(if yes awful naming btw)? It is available(meaning that is either declared in its own file or isn't a inner class in another class)? Also, you're doing things wrong, in the listener's callbacks you get a `FragmentTransaction` that you should use instead of making your own transaction(don't commit it!).

Comment: The names are case sensitive `fragment1 != Fragment1`.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the problem. However, now it doesn't remove the first fragment's view when I tap on the other tab. They overlap. Isn't detach working?

Comment: By the way, I am using support library, so I saw this comment and applied about FragmentTransaction : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14685927/1463542

Comment: Check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642295/actionbar-tab-contents-overlapping/19644639#19644639